# Abrir arquivos recentes no vim

Tags: vim

Qual o modo mais eficiente de abrir um arquivo já aberto antes no vim?

Tenho usando o seguinte recurso

```
:browse oldfiles
```

Mas é preciso ir até o fim da página para inserir o número do documento a ser aberto.
Há como tornar esse processo mais simples?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eu uso muito esse comando. Você não precisa ir até o final da página para inserir o número do documento. Se você pressionar "q", o vim permitirá que você digite o número do documento. Ele mostrará imediatamente este texto:

```
Type number and <enter> (empty cancels)
```

Se o vim estiver configurado para português, mostrará este texto:

```
Digite um número e <Enter> (deixe em branco para cancelar):
```

Comment: it is no easy feat to write a perfectly translatable text, and you did it! Also, learned a new vim trick with you, thanks!

Comment: Obrigado :) Estou feliz por poder ajudar.

Comment: Como nunca percebi isso antes!! Muito obrigado pela excelente dica.